# Question aboute proof of Herglotz functions

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I'm following Geral Teschls' *Mathematical Methods in Quantum Mechanics* and trying to understand the proof that every Herglotz-Nevanlinna function $F$ (holomorphic function which maps the upper half-plane $\mathbb{C}^+$ to the closed upper half-plane $\bar{\mathbb{C}}^+$) is of the form
$$
F(z) = bz +a+\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1+z\lambda}{\lambda-z} \frac{d\mu(\lambda)}{1+\lambda^2}
$$
The general idea of the proof is that
$$
C(z)=-iF\left( \frac{i-z}{i+z} \right)
$$
is Caratheodory function, i.e., holomorphic and maps the open unit disc $\mathbb{D}$ into the closed right-half plane $\{ \Re z \ge 0\}$. By Poisson's formula (and some fancy steps in between), you can show that
$$
C(z) = ic +\int_{[-\pi,\pi]} \frac{e^{i\varphi} +z}{e^{i\varphi} -z} d\nu (\varphi)
$$
for some real $c$ and finite measure $\nu$.

**Question**. I don't quite understand why $\nu\{-\pi,\pi\}$ may be nonzero, since the Poisson formula can be easily taken over $(-\pi,\pi)$ instead of $[-\pi,\pi]$. However, if $\nu\{-\pi,\pi\}=0$ were always true, $b=0$ is always true and there would be no need to write $F$ with the coefficient $b$.

**EDIT**. Let me try to be a little more specific. The proof of $C(z)$ (which I know) goes like this. Since $C(z)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$, we see that if $0<r<1$, then by Poisson's formula, we have
$$
\Re C(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{[-\pi,\pi]}\Re\left( \frac{re^{i\varphi} +z}{re^{i\varphi} -z}\right) \Re C(re^{i\varphi})d\varphi, \quad |z|<1
$$
If we define
$$
d\nu_r(\varphi)=\Re C(re^{i\varphi}) \frac{d\varphi}{2\pi}
$$
then $\nu_r$ is a positive measure on $[-\pi,\pi]$. Hence,
$$
\Re C(z) = \int_{[-\pi,\pi]}P_r (\varphi) d\nu_r (\varphi), \quad P_r(\varphi) = \Re\left( \frac{re^{i\varphi} +z}{re^{i\varphi} -z}\right)
$$
Since $P_r(\varphi) \to P_1(\varphi)$ uniformly on $[-\pi,\pi]$, we can approximate $\Re C(z)$ with
$$
\int_{[-\pi,\pi]}P_1 (\varphi) d\nu_r (\varphi)
$$
Since $\nu_r(\varphi)$ are positive measures with $\nu_r[-\pi,\pi]=\Re C(0)$, we see that by Banach-Alaoglue, it converges vaguely to some positive measure $\nu$ and thus we have
$$
\Re C(z) = \int \Re\left( \frac{e^{i\varphi} +z}{e^{i\varphi} -z}\right) d\nu(\varphi)
$$
**As far as I can tell**, the same proof seems to apply if I were to change the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ to $(-\pi,\pi)$, which would imply the $\nu\{-\pi,\pi\}=0$, so which step am I overlooking?

**EDIT 2**. I think the problem is that if we were to restrict the interval to $(-\pi,\pi)$, even though there would be a positive measure $\nu$ such that $\nu_r \to \nu$ vaguely (as linear functionals on $C_0(-\pi,\pi)$), the term $P_1(\varphi)$ would not be in $C_0(-\pi,\pi)$ and thus the last step is invalid. Many thanks to @Conrad

Comment: Herglotz functions on the unit disc (functions positive real part, $f(0)=1$) require general unit positive measures not only absolutely continuous ones wr lebesgue measure as the former set is weak star compact not the latter; a good example is $\frac {1-z}{1+z}$ that is the integral of the poisson kernel again the point mass at $\pi$; this where the $b$ above comes

Comment: @Conrad Thanks for the example. I now can see that such examples exist, but I'm still quite confused where in the proof does it require that we restrict ourselves to the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ instead of $(-\pi,\pi)$ (as explained in my **edit**)

Comment: $(-\pi, \pi)$ is not compact so it is not necessarily true that $d\nu_r(\varphi)$ has a weak* convergent subsequence; $\frac {1-z}{1+z}$ is a good example